# Confusion related to calculation of Hessian and notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, subgradient

I was reading this [paper](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v28/wytock13-supp.pdf) where they have calculate the gradient and hessian of a function as

[image]

[image]

I didn't get what the cross sign means here. Further I am confused about the second row first column term of the hessian. I think it should have been $2Sxx\Theta\Lambda^{-1}\Lambda^{-1}$. However, the results are in different order in the paper. The same is the case with the others like in the 2nd row 2nd column term, it should have been $2Sxx\Lambda^{-1}$

Any guidance?

Comment: The 'cross sign' denotes the Kronecker product, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product